# Out of memory Exception while scaling image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, memory-management, windows-phone-8.1

I am new on Windows phone development. I am scaling an image, first time it scale image good but when I am choose another picture and implement scale on image so I get a
`System.OutOfMemoryException`. On this line

```
ScaleTransform t = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 5, ScaleY = 5 };
```

My code where I am trying to scale image.

```
Image uiElement = new Image() { Source = blurImage };
ScaleTransform t = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 5, ScaleY = 5 };

WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(uiElement, t);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)blurImage.PixelWidth, (int)blurImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);                      
    bmp.SetSource(ms);
    imgholder.Source = null;
    imgholder.Source = bmp;
    ms.Dispose();
}
t = null;
writeableBitmap = null;
uiElement.Source = null;
uiElement = null;
GC.Collect();
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: if you could post exception log to the answer it would really help us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scaling the image by 500%. Is this really what you want? The image or the second image could be too big after this operation.

> Values between 0 and 1 decrease the width of the scaled object; values greater than 1 increase the width of the scaled object. A value of 1 indicates that the object is not scaled in the x-direction.
>
> Negative values flip the scaled object horizontally. Values between 0 and -1 flip the scale object and decrease its width. Values less than -1 flip the object and increase its width. A value of -1 flips the scaled object but does not change its horizontal size.

[ScaleTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user3555472 I see you've unaccepted the answer... what happened?